# The order of list is not as expected

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a list `node_list`.

```
In [1]: node_list
Out[1]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I add nodes to a [NetworkX](https://github.com/networkx/networkx) graph `G` from the `node_list`

```
In [2]: import networkx as nx

In [3]: G = nx.Graph()

In [4]: G.add_nodes_from(node_list)
```

But when I get the list of the nodes, the pattern is changed!

```
In [5]: list(G.nodes())
Out[5]: ['a', 1, 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'g', 'f', 'i', 'h', 'j', 2, 3, 4, 6, 5]
```

I want the `Out[5]` to be in the same pattern as the `node_list` but that didn't happen. How can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the docstring](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/classes/graph.py#L208) of `NetworkX.Graph` :

```
Examples
--------
Create a graph object that tracks the order nodes are added.
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> class OrderedNodeGraph(nx.Graph):
...     node_dict_factory=OrderedDict
>>> G=OrderedNodeGraph()
>>> G.add_nodes_from( (2,1) )
>>> G.nodes()
[2, 1]
>>> G.add_edges_from( ((2,2), (2,1), (1,1)) )
>>> G.edges()
[(2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 1)]
```